# How can I pass custom props to SwiperSlide and get it onSlideChange function?

Tags: reactjs, swiper.js

I am in a different situation. I am using Swiper.js for my React app. I need to change app theme color on slide changes and it have to be dynamic. That's I need to pass some props to SwiperSlide and get this props on slide change. How can I handle that ?

```html
    <Swiper
      id="pathway-slider"
      slidesPerView={1}
      onSlideChange={(swiper) => {
        console.log("Slide index changed to: ", swiper);
      }}
    >
      <SwiperSlide>
          Slide 1
      </SwiperSlide>
      
      <SwiperSlide>
          Slide 2
      </SwiperSlide>
    </Swiper>
```

When I console.log(swiper) it gives me huge object where I can access activeSlideIndex or etc. But how can I pass custom data to that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a way with a custom slide component:

```js
/**
 * props contains: isActive, isDuplicate, isnNext, isPrev, isVisible
 */
const SlideContent = ({...props}) => {
  return (
    <>
      {props.isActive && 'isActive'}
    </>
  )
}

<Swiper>
  <SwiperSlide>
    {SlideContent}
  </SwiperSlide>
</Swiper>
```

Tried to do it directly with `<SwiperSlide>`, but that seems to break the functionality.